# change log in password

Tags: login-screen

Ubuntu 17.10 (x11).

Is it possible for an administrative user to have a password for the login screen that is different from the password for elevated permissions?  If so, how do I change the login password for just the login screen?

Comment: muru - Ummmm....  Not a "possible" duplicate - that is EXACTLY what I am asking.  I did try to find duplicates, I missed this one, thanks for finding this one.